# Best practice UI guide?

Tags: winforms, user-interface

I'm looking for a guide about UI best practices, in particular for **Windows winform applications**, with recommendations or descriptions of control sizes,  label/textbox alignment, choice of checkbox or radio, etc.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you're looking to create an application with the look and feel of a "typical" Windows application, the [Windows desktop UI Guidelines documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/uxguide/guidelines) is probably a good place to start.  It does contain recommendations for the points mentioned in your question, as well as many others that you probably haven't even considered yet.

Comment: _Design applications for the Windows desktop_ **not** for ***Windows Forms*** neither 
*Design of Large .NET Applications: Best Practices*

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was asked many years ago.
For Windows current design guidelines at:
[Design and code Windows apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/)

Comment: I think that page is for WINUI3 isn't it?